# Connection refused on port 9283 even though the port is open and listening

Tags: networking, iptables, port

I am running a [Grocy](https://grocy.info/) docker [container](https://github.com/linuxserver/docker-grocy) on a Raspberry Pi 2 [fresh Raspbian install]; the container is running, with port `80` mapped to port `9283` on the host:

- Verify container is running via `docker ps`:

  ```
  CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                       COMMAND   CREATED        STATUS        PORTS                                     NAMES
  473614c3f885   ghcr.io/linuxserver/grocy   "/init"   16 hours ago   Up 15 hours   443/tcp, 6781/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9283->80/tcp   grocy
  ```
- Verify port `9283` is open and listening via `sudo iptables -L`:

  ```
  Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
  target    prot opt source       destination
  ACCEPT    tcp  --  anywhere     anywhere      tcp dpt:9283
  ```

  `sudo netstat -pant`:

  ```
  Active Internet connections (servers and established)

  Proto   Recv-Q  Send-Q  Local Address       Foreign Address         State         PID/Program name
  tcp          0      0   0.0.0.0:9283        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN        632/docker-proxy
  tcp          0      0   0.0.0.0:22          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN        428/sshd
  tcp          0      0   192.168.1.40:22     192.168.1.11:58703      ESTABLISHED   1708/sshd: pi [priv
  tcp6         0      0   :::22               :::*                    LISTEN        428/sshd
  ```
- I can connect to `127.0.0.1`, however the connection to `192.168.1.40` [Pi] is refused, either on the Pi itself or from my local network: 
   `wget 127.0.0.1:9283`:

  ```
  --2021-03-06 10:49:51--  http://127.0.0.1:9283/
    Connecting to 127.0.0.1:9283... connected.
    HTTP request sent, awaiting response... Read error (Connection reset by peer) in headers.
  ```

  `wget 192.168.1.40:9283`:

  ```
  --2021-03-06 10:52:09--  http://192.168.1.40:9283/
    Connecting to 192.168.1.40:9283... failed: Connection refused.
  ```

I have read the answer to this [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/725262/what-causes-the-connection-refused-message), but because the port is listening, I assume a firewall on the Pi is blocking the port and I have no idea how to open the port (port `22` for SSH is open, but does not appear in `iptables`).

Is there another layer of port blocking somewhere?

- `iptables -L`:

  ```
  Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
  target                    prot opt source       destination
  ACCEPT                    tcp  --  anywhere     anywhere      tcp dpt:9283

  Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
  target                    prot opt source       destination
  DOCKER-USER               all  --  anywhere     anywhere
  DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  anywhere     anywhere
  ACCEPT                    all  --  anywhere     anywhere      ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
  DOCKER                    all  --  anywhere     anywhere
  ACCEPT                    all  --  anywhere     anywhere
  ACCEPT                    all  --  anywhere     anywhere
  ACCEPT                    all  --  anywhere     anywhere      ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
  DOCKER                    all  --  anywhere     anywhere
  ACCEPT                    all  --  anywhere     anywhere
  ACCEPT                    all  --  anywhere     anywhere

  Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
  target                    prot opt source       destination

  Chain DOCKER (2 references)
  target                    prot opt source       destination
  ACCEPT                    tcp  --  anywhere     172.18.0.2    tcp dpt:http

  Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
  target                    prot opt source       destination
  DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere     anywhere
  DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere     anywhere
  RETURN                    all  --  anywhere     anywhere

  Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (2 references)
  target                    prot opt source       destination
  DROP                      all  --  anywhere     anywhere
  DROP                      all  --  anywhere     anywhere
  RETURN                    all  --  anywhere     anywhere

  Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
  target                    prot opt source       destination
  RETURN                    all  --  anywhere     anywhere
  ```
- `nft list ruleset`:

  ```
  table ip filter {
    chain INPUT {
      type filter hook input priority 0; policy accept;
      iifname "eth0" meta l4proto tcp tcp dport 9283 counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
    }

    chain FORWARD {
      type filter hook forward priority 0; policy drop;
      counter packets 0 bytes 0 jump DOCKER-USER
      counter packets 0 bytes 0 jump DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1
      oifname "docker0" ct state related,established counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
      oifname "docker0" counter packets 0 bytes 0 jump DOCKER
      iifname "docker0" oifname != "docker0" counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
      iifname "docker0" oifname "docker0" counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
      oifname "br-3075040908de" ct state related,established counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
      oifname "br-3075040908de" counter packets 0 bytes 0 jump DOCKER
      iifname "br-3075040908de" oifname != "br-3075040908de" counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
      iifname "br-3075040908de" oifname "br-3075040908de" counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
    }

    chain OUTPUT {
      type filter hook output priority 0; policy accept;
    }

    chain DOCKER {
      iifname != "br-3075040908de" oifname "br-3075040908de" meta l4proto tcp ip daddr 172.18.0.2 tcp dport 80 counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
    }

    chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 {
      iifname "docker0" oifname != "docker0" counter packets 0 bytes 0 jump DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
      iifname "br-3075040908de" oifname != "br-3075040908de" counter packets 0 bytes 0 jump DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
      counter packets 0 bytes 0 return
    }

    chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 {
      oifname "docker0" counter packets 0 bytes 0 drop
      oifname "br-3075040908de" counter packets 0 bytes 0 drop
      counter packets 0 bytes 0 return
    }

    chain DOCKER-USER {
      counter packets 0 bytes 0 return
    }
  }

  table ip6 filter {
    chain INPUT {
      type filter hook input priority 0; policy accept;
    }

    chain FORWARD {
      type filter hook forward priority 0; policy accept;
    }

    chain OUTPUT {
      type filter hook output priority 0; policy accept;
    }
  }

  table ip nat {
    chain PREROUTING {
      type nat hook prerouting priority -100; policy accept;
      fib daddr type local counter packets 2 bytes 104 jump DOCKER
    }

    chain INPUT {
      type nat hook input priority 100; policy accept;
    }

    chain POSTROUTING {
      type nat hook postrouting priority 100; policy accept;
      oifname != "docker0" ip saddr 172.17.0.0/16 counter packets 0 bytes 0 masquerade
      oifname != "br-3075040908de" ip saddr 172.18.0.0/16 counter packets 0 bytes 0 masquerade
      meta l4proto tcp ip saddr 172.18.0.2 ip daddr 172.18.0.2 tcp dport 80 counter packets 0 bytes 0 masquerade
    }

    chain OUTPUT {
      type nat hook output priority -100; policy accept;
      ip daddr != 127.0.0.0/8 fib daddr type local counter packets 0 bytes 0 jump DOCKER
    }

    chain DOCKER {
      iifname "docker0" counter packets 0 bytes 0 return
      iifname "br-3075040908de" counter packets 0 bytes 0 return
      iifname != "br-3075040908de" meta l4proto tcp tcp dport 9283 counter packets 0 bytes 0 dnat to 172.18.0.2:80
    }
  }
  ```

Comment: You have added a line in iptables, but you don't show _where_ you added it. At the top? At the bottom? Does it happen to be after a "reject everything" rule? Additionally to that, have you checked `nft list ruleset` for non-iptables-based firewall rules?

Comment: @user1686 I have added some more details to my question above. The line is added at the top of iptables. I have installed `nftables` to read the list. I am not sure to be able to read it properly, but it seems to contain the same info as iptables.

Comment: @Vincent When crafting long questions/answers, markdown formatting, such as bulleted lists, goes a long way in enhancing the ease of readability by splitting information into its constituent sections and making it clear what information refers to what paragraph _(analogous to using paragraphs versus a single stream of consciousness)_. It's generally not recommended to split sentences with a code box since it discombobulates.

Comment: Thank you @JW0914 for your advice. I have edited the question to, hopefully, add some clarity.